# How can I do persistent DOM-changes with my firefox-addon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox-addon

I'm trying to write my first firefox addon at the moment. 
The goal is quite simple: I'm trying to find every occurrence of a specific username on a website and replace them with a String. I can search for those occurrences manually, since theres not a huge quantity. This worked for one of the occurrences in the HTML of the website, an element which has an ID and gets displayed in a header on every instance of the website:

```
<a href="/user/MyUserName" id="user-profile-name" class="head-link">MyUserName</a>
```

This is how I  replaced the username with with the String:

```
document.getElementById("user-profile-name").innerHTML = "The String";
```

I tried this and many other methods for the other occurrences, which don't have any id's, they're mainly classes:

```
<a href="/user/MyUsername" class="user um1">MyUserName</a>
```

If I try to change them with the same method, it works the first time I load the addon, but they just change back to the username when I visit a new page (with the same classes used on occurrences of the username (user um1)) or reload the page.

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("um1");
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  list[i].innerHTML = "The String";
}
```

How can I make these changes persistent? The change should only be visual, the addons purpose is to hide a username.

Answer (score 0):

The changes can't be made persistently. They need to be applied every time a page from that site loads. However, doing so is easier if you use [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#user-profile-name,.um1");
for (i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
  list[i].innerHTML = "The String";
}
```